# Awk print lines starting with regex (IP address)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

Im trying to read a file for those lines which has IP address on the first column.

my command below does not return any value.

```
cat test.csv | awk '$1 == "^[[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}]" { print $0 }'
```

The regex can capture IP address.

Tried the below too,

```
cat test_1.csv | awk '$1~/^[[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\]/ {print $0}'
```

**test.csv**

```
1.1.1.1 ipaddress gateway
2.2.2.2 ipaddress_2 firewall
www.google.com domain google
```

Comment: Use regex operator `~` for matching regex. Not `==`. Also, `awk` can read input from file. You do not need use of `cat`. Simply `awk '$1 ~ /^regex/' file`

Comment: Post a minimal example of input and output.

Comment: Why are you putting `[...]` around the regex?  That probably doesn't do what you're hoping for here.

Comment: @sat is correct about `==` and @EricRenouf is correct about `[...]` and you're also missing a final `}`. You should obviously, have tried a briefer regexp and then built up to that long one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it more easily with `grep`:

```
grep -P '^\d+(\.\d+){3}\s' test.csv
```

or

```
grep -P '^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}\s' test.csv
```

Comment: Not sure if this will filter the ip adresses, What about 1.1.1.300?

Comment: It's not easier with grep and that will only work with GNU grep while `awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$/' test.csv`will work with any POSIX awk.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `{1,3}` (Interval expressions) in GNU `awk`, you have to use either `--re-interval` (or) `--posix` option to enable it.

Use :

```
awk --posix '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/' file
```

(OR)

```
awk --re-interval '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/' file
```

From `man awk`:

> r{n,m}
>
> One or two numbers inside braces denote an interval expression.
>   Interval expressions are only available if either **--posix** or
>   **--re-interval** is specified on the command line.

Comment: is there some setting that enables one or both of these options? works fine without either option for me on `GNU Awk 4.1.3`...

Comment: @spasic, It is not working on `GNU Awk 3.1.8`. On `GNU Awk 4` it might be enabled.

Comment: oh ok.. does this work `awk '/^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}\s/' file` with/without those options on `GNU Awk 3.1.8` ?

Comment: @spasic, It will work with those options only on `GNU Awk 3.1.8`.

Comment: RE intervals are enabled by default since gawk 4.0. On older gawks use `--re-interval`, not `--posix`, to enable RE intervals as the latter additionally disables all gawk extensions, e.g. `gensub()`.

Comment: btw your regexp is missing the ending `$` and could be abbreviated to `$1 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$/`